# esriPFS(Picture Filled Symbol) imageData is not displayed on Leaflet Map

Tags: typescript, leaflet, esri, esri-maps, esri-leaflet

Expected Result on Map
[image]

```
import * as L from "leaflet";
import * as esri from  "esri-leaflet"
import "esri-leaflet-renderers";

let _layer = esri.featureLayer({
url: 'https://services.arcgis.com/aA3snZwJfFkVyDuP/ArcGIS/rest/services/airport_districts_and_spheres/FeatureServer/1',
simplifyFactor: 1
});
this.map.addLayer(_layer);
```

Since Esri-leaflet-renderer does not support "symbol-type: esriPFS", is there any way we can render esriPFS (Picture Filled Symbol) on leaflet map?

Comment: I just gave it a try and it shows a polygon. what do you expect to show?

Comment: Is it showing image? I have attached an expected rendered image above.

Comment: No, you are right. Only the polygon.

Comment: This is a good question, especially in light of the fact that esri-leaflet just upgraded to v3, as did a lot of its official esri plugin (geosearch, vectortiles, etc.). I don't see that the esri-leaflet-renderers package updated though, but I would open an issue on their GH asking if they're going to update it for the new esri-leaflet 3 release, and if that update might bring in support for advanced fill types. In the meantime, your fill pattern looks simple - a bunch of green dots.  You may be able to reproduce this manually with [leaflet-pattern](https://github.com/teastman/Leaflet.pattern)

Comment: Thanks @SethLutske, Appreciate your help.
To use leaflet-pattern I need to pass the options which are not available for PFS symbol of FeatureServer renderer object.
Need a some other solution to render picture filled symbol.

Comment: I meant more that you would have to code the pattern again from scratch - a bunch of small green circles shouldn't be too hard to accomlish with leaflet-pattern.  You wouldn't be reading from the FeatureServerm, you'd just be mimicing the renderer from scratch